# Is there a way to use the Windows Certificate Store for Kafka Producer/Consumer encryption (Java Client)?

Tags: java, windows, apache-kafka, ssl-certificate, certificate-store

To the best of my understanding the java client for kafka allows only to submit paths to certificates for client-broker encryption and exclusively .jks files - as shown here [1](https://www.instaclustr.com/support/documentation/kafka/accessing-and-using-kafka/use-kafka-with-java/?_ga=2.267559181.20698764.1617064135-822200387.1606692934).

However, I have the requirement to use certificates from Windows-MY.
One obvious workaround would be to read the Windows-MY certificates via custom java code and save the resulting certificates as .jks files at a place like the Java Certificate Store and, then, submit the corresponding path to a kafka producer/consumer.

My question would be: Is there a more sophisticated solution to this problem? Am I missing somthing? For example, has the Java Client some functionality to submit certificates in-memory - similar to its c/c++ counterpart [2](https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/discussions/3819)?

Comment: Kafka supports PEM files as well, but no, there's no in-memory option that I've seen without using `System.setProperty` to set the cert to a file on disk... So, maybe try reading the Windows-MY cert, and writing to temp directory?